# what is c++ std::map's null keyword?

Tags: c++, dictionary

`map<CString, CString> tmp()`

I want to that funcion return null when it is fail.
but error occur when i return NULL

What is map's keyword means fail

Comment: Like it or not, `tmp` returns a **map**. How it does that and still communicates back to the caller some "failure" condition is entirely up to you. You could always return something like a `std::pair<YourMapTypeHere,bool>` and set the pair's `second` member to `false` to indicate failure, but obviously that would require a return-type change.

Comment: You can change the Return type to map<CString, CString>*, return a map with zero elements, throw an exception, or change the signature to something like bool tmp(map<CString, CString>& ret) and return false when something goes wrong.

Comment: I guess you come from something like Java/C#/Python etc background.  What you are returning is a `map`, not a pointer/reference to `map` which you cannot return a null.  You may want to return an empty `map`, or throw an exception etc.  I guess I need to remind you that your `map` will gone out of scope after the statement you call `tmp()`, which I guess will surprise you

Comment: Similar to `std::pair<std::map<K, V>, bool>`, there is `boost::optional<std::map<K, V>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only pointers can have the value `NULL`<sup>†</sup>. `std::map` is not a pointer. There exists no designated value that represents a failure. The closest analogue to `NULL` would be an empty map but it cannot represent a failure if it is a valid result for success.

If your function should return both a map and also state of success, then your function has multiple outputs. You can return an object containing both the map and the success state:

```
struct process_result {
    map<CString, CString> the_map;
    bool success;
}
```

[Boost optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) is a generalization of this pattern.

Another way to "return" multiple values is to pass some outputs as reference parameters.

Finally, you can throw an exception on failure.

<sup>†</sup> Since c++11. In prior versions of c++, `NULL` was just an integer. `std::map` is not an integer either.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return null from a function of such signature:

```
map<CString, CString> tmp()
```

you can return a pair:

```
std::pair<map<CString, CString>, bool> tmp() {
   map<CString, CString> map;
   return std::make_pair(map, false/*here return false or true*/);
}
```

or return bool and map return in parameter:

```
bool tmp(map<CString, CString>& retMap) {
    return true;
}
```

retMap is a reference so it will modify map object you have privided as argument.

If you really cannot change signature then you are left with throwing an exception.